# Sliding div using css3 translate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to slide a menu and container either left or right using css3 translate. But on clicking on toggle, the menu span appears to slide pretty fast and the container appears to slide to left slowly. Have I written the css styles properly ?

CSS

```
  .animate-left,.animate-left-container {
   transition: all .6s ease-out 0.2s;
  }
  .animate-left-container {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
 .animate-right,.animate-right-container {
   transition: all .6s ease-in 0.2s;
  }
  .animate-right-container {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
 .animate-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-45px);
  margin-left: -45px;
 }

 .animate-right{
   -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
```

JS

```
var container = $(".app-data-container").children();

$('.nav-toggle-button-container').on('click',function(e){

var x = $(container[0]), y= $(container[1]);


if(x.hasClass('animate-left') && y.hasClass('animate-left-container')) {
    x.removeClass('animate-left').addClass('animate-right');
    y.removeClass('animate-left-container').addClass('animate-right-container');
}else if(x.hasClass('animate-right')){
    x.removeClass('animate-right').addClass('animate-left');
    y.removeClass('animate-right-container').addClass('animate-left-container');
}else{
    x.addClass('animate-left');
    y.addClass('animate-left-container');
}
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/2b9e8bq9/

Comment: I think you're just not accounting for the distance which is to be moved.  If 2 different things travel 2 different distances in the same amount of time, one will move faster and the other slower.

Comment: understood your point but is there a way to fix this or is this a limitation of css3 animations

Comment: Adjust the duration of each to fit how you want them to go or make them travel the same distance.  You want the *rate* to be the same and that is calculated by distance/duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a little bit, but I created an example which I hope helps and can, perhaps, simplify your code overall.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      .rate-100pxs, .rate-200pxs {
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0;
        -moz-transition:    all 1s ease 0;
        -o-transition:      all 1s ease 0;
        transition:         all 1s ease 0;
      }
      #cell-1, #cell-2 {
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        width:200px;
      }
      h1 {
        white-space:pre;
        font-size:20px;
      }
      .animation-box {
        position:relative;
        background:#eee;
      }
      .animation-box .rate-200pxs {
        left:200px;
      }
      .animation-box:hover .rate-200pxs {
        left:0px;
      }
      .animation-box .rate-100pxs {
        left:200px;
      }
      .animation-box:hover .rate-100pxs {
        left:100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Distance: 200px    Duration: 1s    Rate:200 px/s</h1>
    <div class="animation-box">
      <div id="cell-1" class="rate-200pxs">Cell 1</div><div id="cell-2" class="rate-200pxs">Cell 2</div>
    </div>
    <h1>Distance: 100px/200px    Duration: 1s    Rate:100 px/s & 200 px/s</h1>
    <div class="animation-box">
      <div id="cell-1" class="rate-100pxs">Cell 1</div><div id="cell-2" class="rate-200pxs">Cell 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```